# How do you check the equality of the inner text of a element using cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a div that has another div inside of it and I want to check the equality of the inner text of the div. I have figured out how to do it using the `invoke('text')` function, but i am wondering if that is the best way. So my question is: how do you check the equality of the inner text of a element using cypress?

```js
it('the channel name should contain be Anakin Skywaler', () => {
  //This works but can we be more specific with our selector
  cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").should('contain', 'Skywalker,Anakin');
})

it('the channel name should equal Skywalker,Anakin', () => {
  cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").find('.channel-name').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(text.trim()).equal('Skywalker,Anakin')
  });
});
```

Please ignore the Star War Reference!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think you can simplify this.

Assuming you have HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div data-test-id="Skywalker,Anakin">
  <div class=".channel-name">Skywalker,Anakin</div>
</div>
```

You can write your assert like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-test-id="Skywalker,Anakin"]').should(
  "have.text",
  "Skywalker,Anakin"
);
```

This passed for me and if I modified the HTML to `Skywalker,Anakin 1` it failed as you would expect. Cypress uses the have.text to look at what is rendered out so it will not worry about any markup and just see what the result is.

This did not work for trimming. you would need to add a callback to do the trimming.

```js
cy.get('[data-test-id="Skywalker,Anakin"]').should(($div) => {
  expect($div.text().trim()).equal("Skywalker,Anakin");
});
```

Comment: It worked for me, in my html that class channel-name is a grand-child of the skywalker,anankin div and it did work. Also know I would never set up a data-test-id that way, this was some actual code of ours, and I have to deal with what i was given, I would prefer it to be the ID attribute and the value to be an integer string..but that is another discussion..

Comment: See: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3887

Answer (score 15):

You can check if a string is contained somewhere inside the div:

```js
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").contains('Skywalker,Anakin');
```

Or, if you need to make sure the div contains *only* the specified text and nothing else, you can tag on this extra assertion:

```js
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").contains('Skywalker,Anakin').should((elem) => {
    expect(elem.text()).to.equal('Skywalker,Anakin');
});
```

---

Explanation:

```js
// Get the data
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']")

        // Get the child or children of the previous command that
        // contain the text - this command fails if no child
        // element is found containing the given text
        .contains('Skywalker,Anakin');
```

```js
// These two lines are explained above
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']")
        .contains('Skywalker,Anakin')

        // Like a .then(), except the contents are retried until
        // all contained assertions are successful or until the
        // command times out
        .should((elem) => {

            // Expect the element's text to exactly equal the
            // string, not just contain it
            expect(elem.text()).to.equal('Skywalker,Anakin');
        });
```

Comment: I don't like using contains, I think in this situation you should check for it being exactly what it should be. Thus I like your 2nd option, I wish it did not have the contains though. Do you have any option without using contains? I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Many thanks for clear explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I think currently this is the best option, because it does not check for contains. I was hoping for a shorter piece of code to do this.

```
it('the channel name should equal Skywalker,Anakin', () => {

    cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").find('.channel-name').invoke('text').then((text) => {
        expect(text.trim()).equal('Skywalker,Anakin')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't believe I didn't see one of the magical cypress `.should` matches. Also I use typescript cypress which gives great lookups/intellisense.

- using should. However, these are exact text matches and may have a lot of spaces

```js
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']")
        .should("have.text", "Skywalker,Anakin")
        .should("have.attr", "data-test-id","Skywalker,Anakin'")
```

- adding a new command would be better such as **shouldHaveTrimmedText**

  - I got it from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3887#issuecomment-522962482
  - but below is the setup to get it working also typescript with type
    lookup

commands.ts

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
    'shouldHaveTrimmedText',
    {
        prevSubject: true,
    },
    (subject, equalTo) => {
        if (isNaN(equalTo)) {
            expect(subject.text().trim().replace(/  +/g, ' ')).to.eq(equalTo);
        } else {
            expect(parseInt(subject.text())).to.eq(equalTo);
        }
        return subject;
    },
);
```

cypress/support/index.d.ts

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
    'shouldHaveTrimmedText',
    {
        prevSubject: true,
    },
    (subject, equalTo) => {
        if (isNaN(equalTo)) {
            // removes double spaces and ending spaces, does not remove special characters such as tabs or \n
            expect(subject.text().trim().replace(/  +/g, ' ')).to.eq(equalTo);
        } else {
            expect(parseInt(subject.text())).to.eq(equalTo);
        }
        return subject;
    },
);
```

tsconfig

```json
{
"types": ["cypress","./cypress/support"]
// or "typeRoots": ... but not both
}
```

```
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']")
        .shouldHaveTrimmedText("Skywalker,Anakin")
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is how you can check exact or partial match for a string in an element:

```
//matches exact text of result string
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']").should('have.text', 'Skywalker,Anakin');

//matches partial text of result string
cy.get("[data-test-id='Skywalker,Anakin']")
.text()
.then(value => {
        cy.log("Text value is :", value);
        expect(value).to.include('Anakin');
});
```

where `text()` is defined in `command.js` file as following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("text", { prevSubject: true }, (subject, options) => {
  return subject.text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## Simple exact matching

```
cy.get('[data-test-id=Skywalker,Anakin]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('equal', 'Skywalker,Anakin')
```