# conditional testing in cypress - testing if element exist

Tags: automation, cypress

in my automation, I'm trying to find an element with a specific text on a page.

to be more specific: every page is a movie info page and has a list of actors and I'm trying to find a specific actor.

if found I will count it -  `count ++`.

if not I will move to the next page and try to find it there.

again and again, until I searched all of the pages.

The problem I encountered is how to get the text of the elements, and whenever the automation does not find the text it crashes.


the element : `<a data-testid="title-cast-item__actor" href="/name/nm2794962?ref_=tt_cl_t_1" class="StyledComponents__ActorName-y9ygcu-1 eyqFnv">Hailee Steinfeld</a>`


the one thing that separates the identification of the elements is the inner text (the name of the actor)

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430983/how-do-you-check-the-equality-of-the-inner-text-of-a-element-using-cypress

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
let x = 0;
cy.visit('/your/pages')
cy.get('[data-testid="title-cast-item__actor"]')
  .contains('Hailee Steinfeld')
  .then(() => cy.log(`Count: ${++x}`));
```

or with visiting all your pages:

```
let x = 0;
const pages = ['/page1', '/page2'];
cy.wrap(pages).each((page) => {
  cy.visit(page);
  cy.get('[data-testid="title-cast-item__actor"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(`Actor: ${text}`);
    if (text === 'Hailee Steinfeld') {
      x++;
    }
    return cy.wrap(x);
  })
}).should('be.greaterThan', 0);
```

But be aware that conditional testing is something that is not recommended by cypress. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#The-problem

Comment: @yuv: If this solves your problem, please mark this answer as accepted.